Why does 「約束」 sound 頭高 here?
This 約束の sounds like やくそくの{HLLLL} to my ear but isn't it a 平板 word?

With this short clip, there's not much more to say than "sure, the accent is indeed strange for standard Japanese". It's likely that it just ended up sounding odd after trying to add theatrical intonation and emotion. If we could hear a longer portion of his lines, we might notice additional details, such as the possibility that he's actually a dialect speaker.

+1. Also in my experience these sort of "intonation gone wrong" things actually are hardly noticable when listening in context, as it gets interpreted properly as interpretation by the listener. Only in isolation (or in some objective analytical sense) does it seem like it has gone beyond the bounds of what intonation allows. This is not to say that one should actively try to replicate this sort of pronunciation since it does sound like the incorrect pitch accent and could lead to confusion in normal situations, but it should be considered acceptable in one's model as a theatrical rendition.
